# Should multiple .WhenAny(...).ToPropertyEx(...) calls overwrite one another?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have an object with two `WhenAnyValues`:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeInt)
    .Select(x => "Bar" + x)
    .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.SomeString);
                
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeInt)
    .Select(x => "Foo" + x)
    .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.SomeString);
```

Testing with 1-4 as inputs yields:

```
1
Foo0
Foo1
2
Foo2
3
Foo3
4
Foo4
```

Swapping the order of the `WhenAnyValue` methods, such that the Bar comes last, results in only Bars being triggered. So it seems that the later `WhenAnyValue` is somehow overwriting the first one. Is this a bug or intended behavior? In case this is a bug, this is from ReactiveUI version 16.3.10.

This issue also appears if the items are filtered with, for instance, Foo only setting on even values and Bar only setting on odd values. You still only get whichever `WhenAnyValue` was the last to be called.

The Foo0 is due to lazy execution, and not related to this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not the `WhenAnyValue()` call, it can be used multiple times on the same property and each of them will fire the observed value change separately. The issue is the `ToPropertyEx()` call or the underlying `ToProperty()` call it redirects to.

The point of `ToProperty()` or `ToPropertyEx()` is to build a value subscription for a specific target property (here `SomeString`). It will configure the subscription and fire a `PropertyChanged` event on value changes. The getter you have for your `SomeString` property will be linked to one generated `ObservableAsPropertyHelper<T>` instance, either with explicit code like

```
public string SomeString => this.someString.Value;
```

(where `this.someString` is of type `ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string>`)
or by using the attribute `[ObservableAsProperty]` of the `Reactive.Fody` library like

```
[ObservableAsProperty]
public string SomeString {get;}
```

There can only be one "getter" configured and it is either the `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` build from your "Bar" subscription or your "Foo" subscription. Keep in mind, the generated `PropertyChangedEvent` event does not carry the actual value, only the property name that was changed. Subscribers have to get the value from somewhere and they use the getter of that property.